# Google Contacts API PUT Invalid XML Document

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am trying to update contact info (Nickname) through Google Contact API, but getting an Invalid XML Document error (400 Bad Request). The request that I am sending is documentation : https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts.

this is my request body:

```html
<entry gd:etag="&amp;quot;Qno-eTVSLit7I2A9XBJUF0kKRAY.&amp;quot;">
  <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/cdatatester%40gmail.com/base/21aa268e8c9eea4c</id>
  <updated>2019-01-17T15:52:03.451Z</updated>
  <app:edited>2019-01-17T15:52:03.451Z</app:edited>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"></category>
  <title>Elizabeth Bennet</title>
  <content>Notes</content>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/cdatatester%40gmail.com/21aa268e8c9eea4c"></link>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/cdatatester%40gmail.com/full/21aa268e8c9eea4c"></link>
  <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/cdatatester%40gmail.com/full/21aa268e8c9eea4c"></link>
  <gd:name>
    <gd:fullName>Elizabeth Bennet</gd:fullName>
    <gd:givenName>Altin2</gd:givenName>
    <gd:familyName>Bennet</gd:familyName>
  </gd:name>
  <gContact:nickname>Altin</gContact:nickname>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="liz@gmail.com"></gd:email>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" address="liz@example.org"></gd:email>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" uri="tel:+1-206-555-1212">(206)555-1212</gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" uri="tel:+1-206-555-1213">(206)555-1213</gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home">
    <gd:formattedAddress>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy
Mountain View
CA</gd:formattedAddress>
    <gd:street>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy</gd:street>
    <gd:city>Mountain View</gd:city>
    <gd:country code="CA">CA</gd:country>
  </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
  <gContact:userDefinedField key="Color" value="Green"></gContact:userDefinedField>
  <gContact:userDefinedField key="Size" value="Medium"></gContact:userDefinedField>
  <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/cdatatester%40gmail.com/base/6"></gContact:groupMembershipInfo>
  <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/cdatatester%40gmail.com/base/782732538ae3faa4"></gContact:groupMembershipInfo>
</entry>
```

Is there anything wrong with my request? I cannot spot any error.